# OpenCV acquisition error with USB camera, but the VideoCapture instance is still opened

Tags: python, opencv, camera, usb

I have the following script:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(INDEX)

while cap.isOpened():
    retval, frame = cap.read()
    # do stuff
```

The script runs on a ARM64 board with Ubuntu 18 and a USB camera. Everything works fine but sometimes the script crashes with the following error:

**/build/opencv-XDqSFW/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:637: error: (-215) !buf.empty() && buf.isContinuous() in function imdecode_**

It seems that no data is being sent by the camera anymore (but the `isOpened` condition still holds). Is there a way to fix the issue without disconnecting and reconnecting the camera?

EDIT: the error is caused by the `retval, frame = cap.read()` line.

Comment: At the end of the code, add this line:`cap.release()`. I think you are not releasing the camera object that is why the next time it says camera is still opened.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you get it in line which use `frame` then you should run it in  `if frame is not None:` or `if reval:` to check if `read()` gives some `frame` - sometimes camera need to "warm up" and it may not send frame but `None`

Comment: @RahulKedia: I'm not getting this error at the beginning of the execution. It starts fine and after some iteration the error is raised. The code is executed only once.

Comment: @furas: I don't have the traceback for now because the error has been logged improperly. I will fix that.